# compat-tensorflow ошибка

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

Мне нужно создать модель для определения обьектов на изображении, но при компиляции вылезает ошибка, что модуль compat не найден, я пытался в Package manager от pycharm найти этот модуль, не нашел. Я так понимаю он должен находится внутри самого Tensorflow, его я обновил, но та же проблема, все инструменты последней версии, устанавливал через pip.

[image: ошибка]

[image: импорты]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: И целиком трейсбэк, пожалуйста. Верхушки нет, а без этого непонятно, из какого файла идет ошибка.

Comment: добавил трейсбек

Comment: И опять картинкой. Ну неудобно людям глаза на скрине ломать.